# Heroku serving old code even after git push

Tags: heroku, git-push

I am experiencing this odd problem where heroku references the old file even after changes have been pushed to it.

I can confirm the changes using git diff. (Heroku does recognize it and push it as well). When i look at the webpage on heroku, the script still uses the old code.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you pushing a local master branch or another branch? What command are you using for your push?

Comment: i used git push heroku master. actually, i have been pushing changes to it and then it suddenly would not recognize any more changes.

Comment: Well that's exactly right. I thought you may have been working in a branch which catches some people out when deploying to heroku. There's no reason that if you're adding your changes, committing then deploying to Heroku for them not to show up as the push will trigger an app restart.

Comment: Is it being cached by the browser?

Comment: thank you james..caching seems to be the problem.